# model missing required attr_accessor for 'photo_file_name' when uploading with paperclip and S3 on heroku

Tags: amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip, attr-accessor

Setting up paperclip with S3 in my linux dev environment was a snap -- everything works out of the box.  However, I can't get it to work on Heroku.

When I try to do an upload, the log shows:

```
Processing ItemsController#create (for 72.177.97.9 at 2010-08-26 16:35:14) [POST]  
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "authenticity_token"=>"0Hy3qvQBHE1gvFVaq32HMy2ZIopelV0BHbrSeHkO1Qw=", "item"=>{"photo"=>#<File:/home/slugs/270862_4aa601b_4b6f/mnt/tmp/RackMultipart20100826-6286-1256pvc-0>, "price"=>"342", "name"=>"a new item", "description"=>"a new item", "sold"=>"0"}}

Paperclip::PaperclipError (Item model missing required attr_accessor for 'photo_file_name'):
```

I found one blog post that referenced this error, and it said to add this to my model:

```
attr_accessor :photo_file_name
attr_accessor :photo_content_type
attr_accessor :photo_file_size
attr_accessor :photo_updated_at
```

That does indeed make the **model missing required attr_accessor for 'photo_file_name'** error go away, but it still doesn't work.  See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575812/no-route-matches-with-paperclip-and-s3-on-heroku) for details.  As I have figured out that with the attr_accessor lines added to my model the uploads fail even on my dev system, I suspect that is not the right answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Found the problem: needed to update the database.

> heroku run rake:db:migrate
>
> heroku restart

I had done what I thought would have accomplished the same thing already:

> heroku rake db:schema:load

but perhaps that doesn't work or something went wrong in the process.

Comment: You may run into trouble running. `heroku run rake:db:migrate` If you do, run this instead `heroku run rake db:migrate` Then `heroku restart`

Comment: Don't use this line: heroku rake db:schema:load . This will delete all your data from tables ! Make a backup if you want to achieve this !

Answer (score 4):

Error like this occurs if you create wrong column type in migration. When you define new table migration for paperclip, you need to specify `t.attachment :name` insted of `t.string :name`. Or `add_attachment :table, :name` when you add new paperclip column in existed table. And now you don't need to add these attributes in `attr_accessor` in model.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this message seems to be because the columns it's missing. Try create a migration creating the columns:

```
class AddPhotoToEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :photo_file_name,    :string
    add_column :events, :photo_content_type, :string
    add_column :events, :photo_file_size,    :integer
    add_column :events, :photo_updated_at,   :datetime
  end
```

end

This work for me, here i have a table events with photo